# reassemble mdadm raid6 with 3 of 5 disks showing possibly out of date?

Tags: linux, raid, mdadm

Not sure what happened but my raid 6 serving as xfs storage stopped to work

First I checked SMART of all devices but non of them showed an error.

```
cat /proc/mdstat
Personalities : [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] 
md0 : inactive dm-8[1](S) dm-9[0](S) dm-11[3](S) dm-7[4](S) dm-10[2](S)
      10736757757 blocks super 1.2

unused devices: <none>
```

My mdadm.conf:

```
ARRAY /dev/md0 level=raid6 num-devices=5 metadata=1.2 UUID=7a7b49b9:ebaf805a:a9ec676c:d6c31c13 
    devices=/dev/dm-11,/dev/dm-10,/dev/dm-9,/dev/dm-8,/dev/dm-7
```

then tried to stop and reassemble it:

```
mdadm --stop /dev/md0
mdadm --assemble --scan -v
mdadm: looking for devices for /dev/md0
mdadm: /dev/dm-12 is not one of /dev/dm-11,/dev/dm-10,/dev/dm-9,/dev/dm-8,/dev/dm-7
mdadm: /dev/dm-6 is not one of /dev/dm-11,/dev/dm-10,/dev/dm-9,/dev/dm-8,/dev/dm-7
mdadm: /dev/dm-5 is not one of /dev/dm-11,/dev/dm-10,/dev/dm-9,/dev/dm-8,/dev/dm-7
mdadm: /dev/dm-4 is not one of /dev/dm-11,/dev/dm-10,/dev/dm-9,/dev/dm-8,/dev/dm-7
mdadm: /dev/dm-3 is not one of /dev/dm-11,/dev/dm-10,/dev/dm-9,/dev/dm-8,/dev/dm-7
mdadm: /dev/dm-2 is not one of /dev/dm-11,/dev/dm-10,/dev/dm-9,/dev/dm-8,/dev/dm-7
mdadm: /dev/dm-1 is not one of /dev/dm-11,/dev/dm-10,/dev/dm-9,/dev/dm-8,/dev/dm-7
mdadm: /dev/dm-0 is not one of /dev/dm-11,/dev/dm-10,/dev/dm-9,/dev/dm-8,/dev/dm-7
mdadm: /dev/sdb is not one of /dev/dm-11,/dev/dm-10,/dev/dm- 9,/dev/dm-8,/dev/dm-7
mdadm: /dev/sdf2 is not one of /dev/dm-11,/dev/dm-10,/dev/dm-9,/dev/dm-8,/dev/dm-7
mdadm: /dev/sdf1 is not one of /dev/dm-11,/dev/dm-10,/dev/dm-9,/dev/dm-8,/dev/dm-7
mdadm: /dev/sdf is not one of /dev/dm-11,/dev/dm-10,/dev/dm-9,/dev/dm-8,/dev/dm-7
mdadm: /dev/sdc is not one of /dev/dm-11,/dev/dm-10,/dev/dm-9,/dev/dm-8,/dev/dm-7
mdadm: /dev/sdd is not one of /dev/dm-11,/dev/dm-10,/dev/dm-9,/dev/dm-8,/dev/dm-7
mdadm: /dev/sde is not one of /dev/dm-11,/dev/dm-10,/dev/dm-9,/dev/dm-8,/dev/dm-7
mdadm: /dev/sda is not one of /dev/dm-11,/dev/dm-10,/dev/dm-9,/dev/dm-8,/dev/dm-7
mdadm: /dev/dm-11 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 3.
mdadm: /dev/dm-10 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 2.
mdadm: /dev/dm-9 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 0.
mdadm: /dev/dm-8 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 1.
mdadm: /dev/dm-7 is identified as a member of /dev/md0, slot 4.
mdadm: added /dev/dm-9 to /dev/md0 as 0 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/dm-10 to /dev/md0 as 2 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/dm-11 to /dev/md0 as 3 (possibly out of date)
mdadm: added /dev/dm-7 to /dev/md0 as 4
mdadm: added /dev/dm-8 to /dev/md0 as 1
mdadm: /dev/md0 assembled from 2 drives - not enough to start the array
```

This gave me the hint to look at the drive states:

```
mdadm --examine /dev/dm-{7..11} | egrep 'dev|Update|Role|State|Chunk Size|Checksum'
/dev/dm-7:
      State : clean
Update Time : Mon Dec 11 09:36:51 2017
   Checksum : 5a065503 - correct
 Chunk Size : 512K
Device Role : Active device 4
Array State : .A..A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/dm-8:
      State : clean
Update Time : Mon Dec 11 09:36:51 2017
   Checksum : b1d36af4 - correct
 Chunk Size : 512K
Device Role : Active device 1
Array State : .A..A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/dm-9:
      State : active
Update Time : Mon Dec 11 09:36:41 2017
   Checksum : bbfe3106 - correct
 Chunk Size : 512K
Device Role : Active device 0
Array State : AA..A ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/dm-10:
      State : active
Update Time : Sun Nov 19 01:00:27 2017
   Checksum : f5b76272 - correct
 Chunk Size : 512K
Device Role : Active device 2
Array State : AAAAA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
/dev/dm-11:
      State : active
Update Time : Tue Dec  5 23:58:46 2017
   Checksum : fab4506f - correct
 Chunk Size : 512K
Device Role : Active device 3
Array State : AA.AA ('A' == active, '.' == missing, 'R' == replacing)
```

First got lost on Nov. 19. 
Second on Dec. 5. 
And the last on Dec. 11 
which caused the other two to stop too.

What are the correct steps to reassemble the raid?